How to get driver value using python?
I want to find this value

I can't just use the cube's X loc since it isnt necessarily the same as the driver value.
I want to be able to print that value, and then I can use it.
It has to be the number that Blender is showing me as Driver Value
I must not have understood the other answer.  I'm pretty new to programming, so I dont know which part of the answer to use.
I'm starting with
active_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
and it has one driver on it so I want to print the driver value of it. What would I put in my print statement to do that?

I tested it. It still works.

I updated the question to be a little more clear.  Sorry i'm new to this

The answer explains how to view what drivers the object has and then demonstrates how to get to the value... It answers the exact question you asked in full. Have you tried copying the lines from the second part of the answer to your Python Console?

In some cases, the driver value is different from the path value. And the driver value is not accessible because it is temporarily created when the UI is opened. But there are still ways to calculate it.
